# How to erase part of a read only file when printing it

Tags: python, io

Practically, I'm reading a file line by line and then printing onto the screen in pygame.

```
textbeingread = f.readline()
```

The code takes 'textbeingread' and uses that to show text on the screen but because each piece of writing is on a separate line it has the little icon to show that there a line underneath it (not exactly sure how to show it). I was just wondering if there was a way (because each line is a different length) to omit the last character in the line but use everything else. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textbeingread = f.readline()[:-1]
```

or

```
textbeingread = f.readline()[:-2]
```

Depends on whether you want to get rid of newline character or also the character before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
textbeingread = f.readline().rstrip("\r\n")
```